# The line import openapiclient "github.com/GIT_USER_ID/GIT_REPO_ID" is added when generating from openapi-generator prompts login

Tags: go, openapi-generator

I am using openapi generator to generate my rest api client. It generates the line

```
openapiclient "github.com/GIT_USER_ID/GIT_REPO_ID"
```

In my imports but I can't for the life of me understand why. Running a `go mod vendor` prompts me to sign in while this line is in place. What is this trying to import? I'm on an enterprise github, which would complicate things. The example README says to add this line but provides no explanation of what it is doing [https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/openapi3/client/petstore/go/go-petstore/README.md#:~:text=%22github.com/GIT_USER_ID/GIT_REPO_ID%22](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/openapi3/client/petstore/go/go-petstore/README.md#:%7E:text=%22github.com/GIT_USER_ID/GIT_REPO_ID%22)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass those to the OpenAPI Generator client as parameters:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate \
    -i openapi.yaml
    -g go \
    -p packageName=mypackage \
    -o /src \
    --git-repo-id my-go-lib/v1 --git-user-id user1 \
```

that will result in

```
openapiclient "github.com/user1/my-go-lib/v1"
```