# How do you specify the module path when using go for openapi generator?

Tags: go, module, code-generation, openapi-generator

When generating a go module with

```bash
openapi-generator-cli generate \
    --input-spec ../spec/myapi.yml \
    --generator-name go \
    --output ./generated/go \
    --package-name myapi \
    --global-property models,supportingFiles
```

the genrated `go.mod` file specifies the module as

```golang
module github.com/GIT_USER_ID/GIT_REPO_ID

go 1.18

require (
)
```

How does one override the `github.com/GIT_USER_ID/GIT_REPO_ID` to be something like: `github.com/myrepo/somedir/myapi`?

I've checked the [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) docs and the [Go Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/go/) docs and neither seem to indicate how to do so.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course as soon as I post I do one more search and find the answer [here](https://github.com/deribit/deribit-api-clients/issues/36) stating one can use the flags `--git-user-id` and `--git-repo-id`.

```bash
openapi-generator-cli generate \
    --input-spec ../spec/myapi.yml \
    --generator-name go \
    --output ./generated/go \
    --package-name myapi \
    --git-user-id myuser \
    --git-repo-id myrepo/somedir/myapi/generated/go \    
    --global-property models,supportingFiles
```

which results in a `mod.go` file of:

```golang
module github.com/myuser/myrepo/somedir/myapi/generated/go

go 1.18

require (
)
```

Comment: Also answered here :-) https://stackoverflow.com/a/75410390/9095551